# Writing Tabulator data changes back to the sever - RESTful

Tags: rest, post, crud, put, tabulator

I just love Tabulator! I am successfully using it to format tables on incoming data retrieved from a REST service from our SaaS. The responses are easy to implement into Tabulator and display on custom form (JSP page).
s
My desire, like many, is to send a POST, PUT, DELETE to the REST service of Jthe tabulator JSON formatted data changes and deletions. I know Tabulator is not intended for CRUD processes, but what is the "best practices" or coding pattern that I can follow from an example of how to implement this. I saw requests to add a Tabulator method that returns changes only, but it is not something currently implemented (or may never be).

I would use a "Save" button to initiate a method/function/call(s) to the REST service to process the JSON. I am a little confused on how I would go about handling what was deleted, what has changed, and what was added to the Virtual DOM so that I could extract that info for the REST call.

Thanks in advance. Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Ron Dog

Answer (score 1):

How you handle this would depend on how you have your code setup in your server, There are several options.

#### Send All Data Back

You could use the ***getData*** function to retrieve all the table data, then send it back in one go, then do an update operation on all the data from the rows in the table, and check to see if any are missing.

```js
var data = table.getData();
```

#### Track Changes

You could use the ***cellEdited*** callback to track when a cell has been edited, and then store the row data for later upload to the server

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    cellEdited:function(cell){
        //cell - cell component
     
        var row = cell.getRow();

        //store row component for later use when sending data back to server 
    },
});
```

You could then take a similar approach for new rows with the ***rowAdded*** Callback

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowAdded:function(row){
        //row - row component

        //store row component for later use when sending data back to server 
    },
});
```

And the same for deleted rows using the ***rowDeleted*** callback

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowDeleted:function(row){
        //row - row component

//store row component for later use when sending data back to server 
    },
});
```